# Basic Javascript questions

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and was working on a basic file but for some reason can't get the innerHTML method to work. Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here?

```
<html>
<head> <title>Testing Javascript</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function GenerateNumber()
{
min = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('miniBox').value);
max = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('maxBox').value);
number = Math.floor (Math.random()*(max+min-1)+min);
document.getElementbyId('outputbox').innerHTML = 'Your value is: ' + number
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p>The numbers are selected between <input type='text' id='miniBox' size=3 value=0> and <input type='text' id='maxBox' size=3 value=10></p>

<input type="button" value="Generate my number: " onClick="GenerateNumber();">

<hr>
<div id="outputbox"></div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, change all of your `getElementbyId` to `getElementById` (capitalize the "B" in "By").

Comment: First line of defence is your browser's developers console. You should be checking that before asking someone else.

Comment: First thing to learn for any language: How to **debug** your code. Use Google Chrome, go to the example I created from your code `->` http://jsfiddle.net/QMGaf/ `<-` and have a look at the console (developer tools): `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementbyId'`. Then you can research what the method name should actually be.

Comment: try running your code through something like jshint.com or jslint.com

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled the method name.  It should be `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementbyId` should be `document.getElementById` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend working with the DOM rather than innerHtml if possible, like:

```
document.getElementById('outputbox').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Your value is: ' + number));
```

http://slayeroffice.com/articles/innerHTML_alternatives/ explains working with the DOM pretty clearly.